# Is there a way to match a fragment identifier (hash fragment) from a URL with purescript-routing?

Tags: purescript, fragment-identifier, halogen

Is it possible to match on a url route that has a [hash fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) at the end of it such as `example.com/examplePath#field1=value&field2=anotherValue` using the [purescript-routing](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-routing/5.1.0) library? This is with the intent to be able to get a `Map String String` value out of a name-value pair in the hash fragment.

(Should I be using a different library (like [purescript-uri](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-uri/4.2.0)) in order to get hash-fragment values out the URL route?)

I know that the `params` function from the `Routing.Match.Class` module in [purescript-routing](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-routing/5.1.0/docs/Routing.Match.Class) can operate on query parameters to do something similar to this - but in this case I'm trying to get the values out of the URL that a user will be redirected to after a Google OAuth login. For a [client-side web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) the access token is returned as a `name=value` pair in the hash (#) fragment of the URI rather than a query string.

The issue is that the cases I create for a URL that has a hash fragment in my `routing :: Match Routes` function do not seem to match and the route matches on my catch all case at the end.

So for a route like `example.com/auth/#field=value`
the corresponding case would be:

```
routing = auth 
       <|> ... the other cases
  where auth = Auth <$> (lit "" *> lit "auth" *> str)
```

but this fails to match on a url if it has a # on the end.